# Automating Oracle Forms based Application - QTP

Tags: qtp

I'm automating an OracleForms based application which is a desktop based application (even though internet explorer is used for launching it). And I selected Web and Oracle Add-in in QTP

The application has a set of fields and user can navigate by pressing Tab button. Two things I can't understand while using QTP.

First one is: when I record an action on a field i.e, if I enter some value in text field, no scripts are generated until I press the Tab Key(during record). Only when I press the tab key the script is generated and the focus moved to either next screen or next field. Need to understand why this happens?

Secondly there is additional  script that is generated when I enter some value and press the Tab Key (given below):

```
     OracleTextField().InvokeSofkey("Return")
```

Couldn't understand the reason why this script is generated. And even if this script is removed and run operation is performed then navigation happens to next field.

To summarize my question with the below code the Tab keys are internally pressed(during run mode) so why this happens in OracleForms based application. What Exactly does the 'Enter' function given below does?

```
OracleTextField().Enter "088989"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge
Until you hit tab recorder still thinks you are typing even if you stopped typing until you move out of the text field it would still be recording your actions.
That's the way for QTP to understand which key is pressed, when you are done entering text, you can disable  smartidentification that will remove those steps